# Finding the value of a for a density probability function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Below is the graph of the density of a random variable $X$.
>   [image]

I know that i have to set up two integrals equals to 1, because the whole area is equals to 1. So this is my attempt.
$\int_2^4 2a\,dx = 4a$
$\int_{-2}^2 a\,dx = 4a$

Comment: The sum is $8a$. This should be $1$.  So $a=?$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use basic geometry.

The area of the left rectangle is
$$\text{base}\times\text{height} = 4a$$
and the other is
$$2(2a) = 4a$$

The sum of the areas is $1$. Hence
$$4a+4a=1 \implies 8a = 1$$
and so $a = 1/8$.

Do you see how this relates to your calculations?

Comment: I already thinking about it.

Comment: Oui I mean, yes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. Consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in all of your questions. Good luck.